# Locus of vertex of triangle moving inside circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

A right triangle with sides $3,4$ and $5$ lies inside the circle $2x^2+2y^2=25$. The triangle is moved inside the circle in such a way that its hypotenuse always forms a chord of the circle. The locus of the vertex opposite to the hypotenuse is ____ ?

A) $2x^2+2y^2=1$

B) $x^2+y^2=1$

C) $x^2+y^2=2$

D) $2x^2+2y^2=5$

From the centre of circle distance to chord is $\displaystyle\frac{5}{2}$ units. From the vertex of triangle, distance to hypotenuse is $2.4$ units. However I am unable to sum up these two parts to obtain the final answer.

Comment: Can you add a diagram to show what is going on?  I was not able to visualize it?

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080326051559AAWkGYX

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,The answer is not well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a construction using ruler and compass, and you will notice that the distance between the center of the circle anf the right-angled corner of the triangle is less than one. Only one of your four possible answers agrees with this situation.

[image: Figure a]

If you prefer to compute this distance, here is a useful illustration:

[image: Figure b]

Since $AB$ with length $5$ is a diagonal in the square $AFBD$, the edges $AD$ and $BD$ are both of length $\frac52\sqrt2$, so $D$ is the center of the circle. You should be able to compute its coordinates, and from that the distance $CD$.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the results are summarized into the following figure.

[image]

$θ = \angle DAX - \angle CAX = sin^{-1} \dfrac {2.5}{2.5√2} – sin^{-1} \dfrac {2.4}{4} = 8.130xxxxxx^0$

In ⊿CAD, $r^2$, the square of the required radius = … by cosine law … = 0.5

Thus, the required equation of the circle is $2x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$

---

Note:- The strange thing is that such a complicated problem is classified as an MC question. There must be some other easier method in finding the solution.

Comment: It's from a book called test of mathematics at 10+2 level aimed at preparation for the entrance for mathematics Institutes of India.

Comment: @Random-15 That must be one of the toughest entrance exam questions.

Comment: Nope. This is still MCQ. Toughest is Chennai Mathematical Institute entrance, as it's not MCQ. Only 20-30 students are selected in it all over India. Last year paper- https://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/ugmath2018.pdf

Comment: Only three hours to complete the paper. My aim is to study in CMI.

Comment: @Random-15 Keep up the good spirit